# htaccess code not working as expected

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have written this in my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule   ^dashboard/(.*)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$   dashboard.php?view=$1&idteam=$2&idplayer=$3&layout=$4  [L]
```

I expect it should give me this :

> ["view"]=>   string(4) "team"   ["idteam"]=>   string(1) "5"
>   ["idplayer"]=>   string(1) "1"   ["layout"]=>   string(10)
>   "editplayer"

But I got this instead :

> array(3) {
>     ["view"]=>
>     string(4) "team"
>     ["idteam"]=>
>     string(1) "5"
>     ["layout"]=>
>     string(13) "1/editplayer"
>   }

This is the URL :

> dashboard/team/5/1/editplayer

This is my whole htaccess :

```
ErrorDocument 404   /index.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wmisports.com 
RewriteRule (.*)   http://www.wmisports.com/$1  [R=301,L]

#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm


RewriteRule   ^dashboard$ dashboard.php [L]
RewriteRule   ^dashboard/view/newteam/(.*)$     dashboard.php?view=newteam&idcaptain=$1  [L]
RewriteRule   ^dashboard/view/team/(.*)$    dashboard.php?view=team&idteam=$1  [L]
RewriteRule   ^dashboard/team/([0-9]+)/(.*)$    dashboard.php?view=team&idteam=$1&layout=$2  [L]
#RewriteRule   ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$      dashboard.php?view=$1&idteam=$2&idplayer=$3&layout=$4  [L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ dashboard.php?view=$1&idteam=$2&idplayer=$3&layout=$4 [L]
```

Please can sombody help understand what is wrong with my code. Thanks

Comment: Try it without the greediness: `^dashboard/(.+?)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+?)$`

Comment: Or better still via `[^/]+`  as in `^dashboard/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$`

Comment: when testing the one of Denis I've got an internal error after testing your proposal

Comment: or even `^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$`

Comment: The one of Michael Changed nothing to the initial result

Comment: The one of claustrofob changed nothing too

Comment: @pollux1er This is a case where you must ensure that you are uploading the correct file version to test... any of these, including your original, should work and none would be expected to produce the behavior you saw because `([0-9]+)` _cannot_ match `1/editplayer`.  Do you have any earlier rewrite rules?

Comment: @pollux1er just checked it, event your initial rule works as expected. Verify if you have no other similar rules in your .htaccess or maybe something in your php script corrupts it.

Comment: oh man, you had to post everything from the start. This rule `RewriteRule   ^dashboard/team/([0-9]+)/(.*)$` actually catch your url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your code with this:

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ dashboard.php?view=$1&idteam=$2&idplayer=$3&layout=$4 [L]
```

**EDIT:** This is how your .htaccess should be:

```
ErrorDocument 404   /index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wmisports\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.wmisports.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ dashboard.php?view=$1&idteam=$2&idplayer=$3&layout=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/team/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ dashboard.php?view=team&idteam=$1&layout=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/view/newteam/(.*)$ dashboard.php?view=newteam&idcaptain=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/view/team/(.*)$ dashboard.php?view=team&idteam=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboard.php [L]
```

Comment: When I vardump var_dump($_GET); die; I still get this array(3) {
  ["view"]=>
  string(4) "team"
  ["idteam"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["layout"]=>
  string(12) "1/editplayer"
}
The variable layout is wrong and idplayer is missing

Comment: I have tested above code and I am getting 4 different array elements in $_GET. Post your latest .htaccess in your question and we can see what's wrong there.

Comment: Ok, let me post all my htaccess

Comment: I did it, let us check and see what's wrong because myself I do not understand! It should normally work!

Comment: With one glance I can tell you that your .htaccess is problematic. Always have rules in the order from most specific to most generic in .htaccess. You have them in reverse.

Comment: anubhava, I will say thank you for your time because I am quite sure myself the code you wrote is worrectn but can't figure out what is wrong! Thanks again for your time, I will try to focus on it and fid out the error on my side.

Comment: You're most welcome. Just fyi that in your code: this rule `^dashboard/team/([0-9]+)/(.*)$` was above my suggested one. And as you can see it matches your URI `dashboard/team/5/1/editplayer` and rest is easy to understand :)